# SQL WHERE MAX(date) within GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've created a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0536/1) with similar data I've got at work (there are actually more columns in the table). Table contains employment details. An employee can have more than one record in the table (couple of fixed-term contracts) as well as different employee_ID (change from 'tixxxxx' into 'pixxxxx'). The PESEL number is the unique personal identification number. ID for past contract can be higher than for actual one as the table is populated with data every day as an extract based on HR data.

What I need to get is:

- at least up-to-date employee_ID (the line where expirationdate is max)
- a whole line with all columns for up-to-date employee_ID
- best if I could get a whole line for up-to-date employee_ID including the very first startdate (important if employee had more than one contract)

It's been some time since I used SQL every day so I'd appreciate any help here. I was thinkig of some nested queries with group by clause, but I never understood well correlated subqueries.

Expected result:

```
ID          Employee_ID PESEL       StartDate  ExpirationDate
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- --------------
1           pi39764     1111        2014-01-01 2016-06-01
2           pi12986     1234        2015-12-01 2099-12-31
5           pi12345     4321        2015-02-01 2099-12-31
```

where the startdate is the very first startdate.

Comment: Do you want this query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0536/6

Comment: Please add all relevant info directly into the question. Links break (especially SQLFiddle).

Comment: @Mihai OP asked for the employee_ID of the line where expirationdate is max. Your query provides two IDs for PESEL=1111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you looking for query like this:

```
SELECT e.*, CASE WHEN actual = StartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS actual_e, first_startdate
FROM Employees AS e
INNER JOIN(SELECT PESEL, MIN(startdate) AS first_startdate , MAX(startdate) AS actual 
  FROM Employees AS e
  GROUP BY PESEL) AS g
  ON g.PESEL = e.PESEL
```

EDIT:
to get actual Employee_ID on every row use sub query:

```
, CASE WHEN actual = StartDate THEN null 
ELSE (SELECT max(a.Employee_ID) FROM Employees AS a WHERE a.PESEL = e.PESEL and a.StartDate = actual)
END AS actual_Employee_ID
```

EDIT:
in Fidde you write MySQL query, for sql server (tag) it is much simplest:

```
SELECT e.*
, LEAD(Employee_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PESEL ORDER BY startdate) actual_Employee_ID
, MIN(startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY PESEL) first_startdate
FROM Employees AS e
```

EDIT (result with last ti):
for all data:

```
SELECT e.*
, first_startdate
, last_t_startdate
, last_startdate
, (SELECT max(employee_ID) FROM dbo.Employees t WHERE startdate = last_t_startdate AND PESEL = e.PESEL) AS last_t_id
, (SELECT max(employee_ID) FROM dbo.Employees t WHERE startdate = last_startdate AND PESEL = e.PESEL) AS last_id
FROM dbo.Employees AS e
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT Min(startdate) AS first_startdate
  , Max(Case When employee_ID LIKE 'ti%' Then startdate End) last_t_startdate
  , Max(startdate) AS last_startdate    
  FROM dbo.Employees
  WHERE PESEL = e.PESEL
  --GROUP BY PESEL
  ) AS g
```

output:

```
ID  Employee_ID PESEL   StartDate   ExpirationDate  first_startdate last_t_startdate    last_startdate  last_t_id   last_id
1   pi39764 1111    2015-01-01  2016-06-01  2014-01-01  2014-01-01  2015-01-01  ti00001 pi39764
2   pi12986 1234    2015-12-01  2099-12-31  2015-12-01  NULL    2015-12-01  NULL    pi12986
3   ti00001 1111    2014-01-01  2014-12-31  2014-01-01  2014-01-01  2015-01-01  ti00001 pi39764
4   pi12345 4321    2015-02-01  2015-06-30  2015-02-01  NULL    2016-01-01  NULL    pi12345
5   pi12345 4321    2016-01-01  2099-12-31  2015-02-01  NULL    2016-01-01  NULL    pi12345
6   pi12345 4321    2015-07-01  2015-12-31  2015-02-01  NULL    2016-01-01  NULL    pi12345
```

for grouped data:

```
SELECT pesel
, first_startdate
, last_t_startdate
, last_startdate
, (SELECT max(employee_ID) FROM dbo.Employees t WHERE startdate = last_t_startdate AND PESEL = g.PESEL) last_t_id
, (SELECT max(employee_ID) FROM dbo.Employees t WHERE startdate = last_startdate AND PESEL = g.PESEL) last_id
FROM (
  SELECT PESEL
  , Min(startdate) AS first_startdate
  , Max(Case When employee_ID LIKE 'ti%' Then startdate End) AS last_t_startdate 
  , Max(startdate) AS last_startdate
  FROM dbo.Employees
  GROUP BY PESEL) AS g
```

output:

```
pesel   first_startdate last_t_startdate    last_startdate  last_t_id   last_id
1111    2014-01-01  2014-01-01  2015-01-01  ti00001 pi39764
1234    2015-12-01  NULL    2015-12-01  NULL    pi12986
4321    2015-02-01  NULL    2016-01-01  NULL    pi12345
```

Comment: if all Employees have not expirationdate then you don't get expected result, that way I'm using MAX(startdate) to compare with startdate

Comment: It still returns two IDs for the same PESEL number. I'd like to get only one ID per each PESEL number - the most up-to-date, e.g 1111 - it returns a line with a past ID and past contract dates.

Comment: Thank you, that's correct. Is there a way to ommit additional column actual_e in results ? How could I list necessary columns instead of using e.* ? I tried and got an error ?

Comment: it isn't necessary, delete it from `,` to alias

Comment: Quite often employees change employeeID from tixxxx to pixxxx. They can have even multiple tixxxx before they get pixxxx. What would be the query, if I'd like to get the latest tixxxx ID from all an employee had before changing the employeeID to pixxxx ?

Comment: with version of sql server you have?

Comment: I have some invalid column name errors, incorect syntax near select and 'as' key words and e.pesel multi-part identifier http://postimg.org/image/dq55gql5j/

Comment: Almost ok - an incorrect syntax error near ON. An ON clause without a join ?

About the query for grouped data, where should I put GROUP BY clause becasue it should be included somwhere, shouldn't it ?

Comment: i don't use `OUTER APPLY` clause very often, it need join condition in `WHERE` clause, corrected, and of course need `GROUP BY` on selected field (PESEL)

Comment: I've added a row to have two different tixxxxx ID for the same PESEL and both queries worked great (after adding a WHERE last_t_id is not null clause to remove some redundant records, I can get just the last tixxxxx). I'll have to think through now, how these queries work, both seem to be complicated. Thank you so much Adam.

Comment: read about [OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), if is like subquery witch multiple output fields, used like functions with [OVER Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: added missing condition in subquery: `AND PESEL = e.PESEL`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e1.employee_id, e.pesel, e.maxdate
FROM (
      SELECT pesel, MAX(expirationdate) as maxdate
      FROM employees
      GROUP BY pesel
) e
INNER JOIN employees e1
ON e.pesel = e1.pesel AND e.maxdate = e1.expirationdate
```

Output:

```
| Employee_ID | pesel |                    maxdate |
|-------------|-------|----------------------------|
|     pi39764 |  1111 |     June, 01 2016 00:00:00 |
|     pi12986 |  1234 | December, 31 2099 00:00:00 |
|     pi12345 |  4321 | December, 31 2099 00:00:00 |
```

To find the first date and the last date for each `PESEL`, use:

```
SELECT e1.employee_id, e.pesel, e.startdate, e.enddate
FROM (
      SELECT pesel, 
           MIN(startdate) as startdate, 
           MAX(expirationdate) as enddate
      FROM employees
      GROUP BY pesel
) e
INNER JOIN employees e1
ON e.pesel = e1.pesel AND e.enddate = e1.expirationdate
```

Comment: That's correct. How would it be with getting also the very first startdate for these lines so I could see up-to-date: employee_ID, PESEL, expirationdate and the ver first startdate in one line ? How is it possible that you used employee_id in nested query while it's not contained in group by clause?

Comment: @Guido Column 'employees.Employee_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Sorry, my bad. I checked this against the wrong server version, and `employee_id` in the nested `SELECT` wasn't necessary anyway for the query, since this field is taken from table `e1`. Corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: Still this is not correct query... Startdates are wrong. First is correct solution, the second is yours: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0536/12 I'd really like to see your query correct so I can analyze and learn on this example.

Comment: @kkris77 Problem is, it should have been `MIN(startdate) as startdate` instead of `MIN(expirationdate) as startdate`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0536/21 Corrected this again.

Comment: @Guido I've just checked it on real data at work and it gave me a little more results than Adam Silenko answer...

Answer (score 1):

Use the SUBTRING_INDEX with GROUP_CONCAT trick to get all the columns

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Employee_ID ORDER BY StartDate DESC),',',1),
PESEL,MIN(StartDate),MAX(ExpirationDate)
from employees
GROUP BY PESEL
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 1):

so try this:

```
SELECT ID, Employee_ID, PESEL, first_startdate AS StartDate, ExpirationDate
FROM (
    SELECT e.*
    , LEAD (Employee_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PESEL ORDER BY startdate) actual_Employee_ID
    , MIN(startdate) OVER (PARTITION BY PESEL) first_startdate
    FROM Employees AS e) AS x
WHERE actual_Employee_ID is null
```

then you get:

```
| ID | Employee_ID | PESEL |  StartDate | ExpirationDate |
|----|-------------|-------|------------|----------------|
|  1 |     pi39764 |  1111 | 2014-01-01 |     2016-06-01 |
|  2 |     pi12986 |  1234 | 2015-12-01 |     2099-12-31 |
|  5 |     pi12345 |  4321 | 2015-02-01 |     2099-12-31 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0536/7

Comment: Thanks. I've read recently about OVER and PARTITION BY and it seemed possible to use in this case  but still I don't get it so I guess I could analyze it on this case
It'd be great to get the same result using query RDBS independent without additional columns, I'll get  into solutions I've received here.

Comment: read about [LEAD](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lead.php) and about [Analytic Functions (Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh213234%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)